# How to Display "%" in batch output?

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe

I am running the following batch program,

```
@echo off
:main
cls
echo 1%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo 2%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo 100%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto main
```

My problem is, it doesn't displaying % symbol in output. pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the % by typing it twice.

example:

```
echo 1%%
```